# Magento 2.x.x have default issue in grid pagination

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2.x.x, if we are on catalog product grid, there we are not 3rd page and edit/open any product. After that we click on back button then we redirect to grid with 1 page rather than 3rd(previous) page.

This issue with sales order and custom grid also.
It means its magento 2 default issue.

Please help me how can we fix it.

Thank you

Comment: Is there anyone who got same issue ?

Comment: This is magneto 2 default issue, No body got this issue: really Strange